# Modifying region of memory - returns 0xCC VC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, self-modifying

I am modifying some sections of an executable code compiled in a dll. But a single byte at a fixed address from the entire segment that I am modifying can't be changed, not even read.

The code is very simple:

```
SEGMENT_DATA segInfo = getSegmentInfo(mHandle, segmentName);

if (segInfo.inFileSegmentAddr == 0) return false;

DWORD mOlProtection;
DWORD mOlProtection_1;

if (segInfo.architecture != MY_ARCH) {
    printf(" Not the same architecture!\n");
    return 0;
}

if(VirtualProtect((LPVOID)segInfo.segmentAddr, segInfo.segmentSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &mOlProtection)==0) return false;
DWORD i=0;
for (size_t k = 0; k < segInfo.segmentSize; k++) {
    BYTE *lpByteValue = (BYTE*)(segInfo.segmentAddr + k);

    BYTE temp = *lpByteValue;
    *lpByteValue = temp ^ lDecryptionKey[i];
    i++;
    i %= decryptionKeyLength;
}

if(VirtualProtect((LPVOID)segInfo.segmentAddr, segInfo.segmentSize, mOlProtection, &mOlProtection_1)==0) return false;
```

**Observations:**

1. Before I modify the memory, I "unprotect" the region with `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` flag.
2. Memory View in visual studio clearly shows me the value at that particular address. Even weirder is that in the second I modify the value manually from the debugger, my code is also able to change that value.
3. `temp` variable in the example code contains the value `0xCC`
4. This byte is literally the only one unchanged in a sea of hundred other bytes. It is the only byte marked black in Memory View (the rest are red because they were changed)
5. Dll is compiled in Debug/x86 . /MTd flag set. No random address (/DYNAMICBASE : NO , /FIXED: NO). No Whole program optimization.
6. The unmodified byte IS NOT a variable. So it can't be "uninitialized". It is actually a very important byte: it is the instruction opcode. Everything crashes on that byte.
7. The decryption routine (XOR code) has no effect on the error. I step into the code and look at `temp`'s value before it reaches the `xor`. This means the decryption key is never used and therefore it can't cause the problem.
8. Virtual protect succeeds.

**Snapshots**:
[image: The black byte cannot be read or written to although visaul studio can display it]

[image: Visual studio can read the address]
Visual studio can read the address

---

[image: Can't read byte inside program]
Can't read byte inside program

---

I know it's not the value of the byte at that single address that is causing problems (because I found other bytes with the same value that were processed successfully). Perhaps the byte is still "protected"?

Why is this happening?

Comment: Does your decryption key contain a few zero bytes in it?

Comment: Could you provide more context, along with a short code we can compile and use to test this?

Comment: No the key doesn't contain zeros. And regarding the compiling : I can't provide any aditional code. But I want to know only this: that there's no hidden "feature" of virtualprotect or another obvious memory-behaviour that would generate this error. If the code I provided wouldn't normally generate this error , at least you have provided me with a clue: that the error is somewhere else, burried in my code.

Comment: In what circumstances would by the way visual studio return 0xCC ? I found something related to unitializd memory. Could this be?

Comment: Added more details

Comment: The problem really is not from the decryption code. The temp variable is the point of interest. It holds 0xCC. It's a simple memory read. No code should interfere with that

Comment: I will not be able to respond until tomorrow.

Comment: 0xCC means uninitialized memory. [When and why will an OS initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Comment: But how can it be uninitialized? After a few lines of code that section of memory that I am modifying will be executed. And besides I can clearly see the value in Memory View

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that your key either contains a null byte, or is shorter than you think: the absence of check or relation between `i` and `segInfo.segmentSize` looks fishy.

Comment: The key does nothing. I step into the code and when `lpByteValue` reaches the address of that weird byte I look at `temp`'s value. I don't event execute that XOR. `temp`'s value is 0xCC. It has nothing to do with the decryption code. I could as well remove all of that code. And the code I provided is modified. That `i` is properly checked in the original code. I will edit the question.

Comment: What about the fixup table? How do you handle that?

Comment: What...fixup? I will do some research. (you mean relocations? Because if you do then I handle it correctly. Actually this problematic-byte is the opcode and the next 4 bytes is the data. But it's just memory...it can't know what I intend to do with it. I am not executing that code, just modifying it )

Comment: Yes relocations. Or link with /FIXED:YES. Also, check that VirtualProtect actually succeeded.

Comment: Should I mention the entire code is debugged on a VM ?

Comment: Good ideea. I didn't check if VirtualProtect succeeded. I will test that

Comment: I don't understand. The address is there, I can see the entire memory, I can change everything I want, visual studio sees it , but despite all that the deferencing operator JUST returns 0xCC. Why? Can I debug visual studio itself?  Perhpas it has something to do with casting? Perhaps unsigned/signed? I really don't know what to look for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could very well deal with a very common scenario of `Software Breakpoints`. 
`Software breakpoints` are in fact set by replacing the instruction to be breakpointed with a breakpoint instruction.

The breakpoint instruction is present in most CPUs, and usually as short as the shortest instruction, so only `one byte on x86 (0xCC, INT 3)`.

As I don't know if there are any breakpoints at all in your source I can only assume that this is your problem.

Comment: Yes indeed. I had a breakpoint exactly on that instruction. That breakpoint explains a lot